# Apiaxle is not running in my system

Tags: node.js, apiaxle

I Followed the instructions given in http://apiaxle.com/docs/try-it-now/. In between i received a warn message

```
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/0.10.37"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/apiaxle-repl/node_modules/apiaxle-base/node_modules/hiredis/.node-gyp"
```

And finally everything installed. But when i type apiaxle in my terminal nothing happend. What i am doing wrong. Please share your ideas.